# How to print status of a committed file in JGit

Tags: jgit

I need to print the status of committed files in JGit,whether it is added ,removed,changed etc.For that i have initially cloned the remote repository and I got the details of commit id,author name,author mail id,date and time.But when I try to print the status using IndexDiff/Status classes, I get null values.

I need to know is it possible to get status of committed files in a remote repository with or without cloning.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InvalidRemoteException, TransportException, GitAPIException {
                       String remote = "http://192.168.215.29:9090/technology-evaluation/patchgitpluginsample.git";
            File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
            localPath.delete();
            Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remote)
                      .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("sarathb", "findme"))
                      .setDirectory(localPath)
                      .call();

    Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(localPath.getAbsolutePath(), ".git"));
            System.out.println(repository);
    List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().call();
            for (Ref ref : branches) 
            {

                System.out.println(ref.getName());

            }

            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();

            for (RevCommit revCommit : commits) {
                System.out.println("");
                RevTree tree=revCommit.getTree();
                /*System.out.println(revCommit.getName());*/
                System.out.println("COMMIT : "+revCommit);
                System.out.println("COMMIT MESSAGE : "+revCommit.getFullMessage());
                System.out.println("AUTHOR NAME : "+revCommit.getAuthorIdent().getName());
                System.out.println("AUTHOR E-MAIL ID : "+revCommit.getAuthorIdent().getEmailAddress());
                System.out.println("DATE/TIME : "+revCommit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen());
        Status status=git.status().call();
System.out.println("added:"+status.getAdded()); 
        System.out.println("removed:"+status.getRemoved());
            TreeWalk treewalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
            treewalk.addTree(tree);
            treewalk.setRecursive(true);
     while (treewalk.next())
            {
                if(treewalk.getNameString().contains(".java"))
                System.out.println("FILE COMMITTED : "+treewalk.getNameString());
                }
    }}}
```

Comment: You need to first clone the repository to get access to the commits and files it contains. Can you post the code that you tried with so far?

Comment: here i am getting every details like the commit,id,author name,mail id,date and time but not the status. I used classes like status,indexDiff but no use it printed null values

Comment: You can use the `IndexDiff` to see which files were added/removed/changed between a commit, the index and the work directory. Is that what you want? If you 'get null values', which values exactly are null and what would you expect them to be?

Comment: Actually i tried that way too...indexDiff was used instead of status class,but again the output was [].suppose if i commit a file 'x' in git,the git UI shows that x is added,if i remove 'y',it shows y is removed.

Comment: Which _output_ do you mean? If you commit a file, it will not be returned in IndexDiff#getAdded()/getRemoved()/getChanged() because it is in sync with the commit it is compared to. Thus if a file is not listed in any of the IndexDiff sets it means that the file is in sync.

Comment: In simple words,i need to print the details of a '.java' file added/removed from git remote repository.
the details must include the author name,author mail id,date,commit msg and the status(added/removed/modified etc...).please help me with the code snippet.

Comment: suppose i committed a file 'x' to my remote repository.Now how can we make print that "x was added few hours before by Hilmi " using Jgit. suppose i deleted a file 'y' from my remote repository hw can we make print "y was removed a few hrs before by Hilmi".Is it possible without cloning? if not please help with cloning.

Comment: With Git, you cannot commit something directly to a remote repository. A commit is always made to the local repository. Local and remote repositories are synced through pushing (publishing changes to remote) and fetching (getting changes from remote) commits that are new to the other side.

Comment: then,How do we get the name of files commited to remote repository and it's comit details including the file name and it's status?

Comment: In Git we have a UI which gives red colour for a removed file and green colour for an added file.So by looking we can understand which are the added and which are removed.How can we get those details using JGit?